# How can we add a new operator in a Int class in Dart language for edit or calculate any specific progress?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, integer, operators

How can we add a new operator in a Int class in Dart language for edit or calculate any specific progress ?

Comment: You can use extension methods to add operators, but `int` already supports most operators, so you won't be able to use them.  Do you have an example for what you specifically want to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about operator overloading we cannot do that to existing class but we can use extension methods to extend the functionality

[Docs for extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

```dart
extension IntExtensions on int {
  int someFunction() {
    // Do something
  }
}

print(5.someFunction());
```